# Sum of $x_i^2$ given sum $x_i$

Tags: statistics

I know
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 100$
I also know that 
$s^2 = 10$ for this sample(sample variance)

Is there anyway to figure out $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2$ given this information?

Comment: Do you know $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and
let $\overline{x}$ be the mean of the sample, i.e. $\overline{x}=\ell/n$.
\begin{align*}
s^2 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x})^2= \frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\overline{x}+\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{x}^2\Bigg)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\ell\overline{x}+n\overline{x}^2\Bigg)= \frac{1}{n}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-\frac{\ell^2}{n}\Bigg).\\
%
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 = ns^2 +\frac{\ell^2}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know $n$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 = n\left[s^2+\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2 \right]= 10n+\frac{10000}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: And, conversely, if you don't know $n$, then you can't find $n$ from the given information, so we can't find $\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i$ either.